# Golf App, Activity with 9 fragments, get the scores?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Golf app :

I have a tabbed activity with 9 fragments (the holes)

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch(position){
            case 0: return HoleFragment.newInstance("1","3", "160", "hole1");
            case 1 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("2","3", "160m", "hole2");
            case 2 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("3","3", "125m", "hole3");
            case 3 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("4","3", "90m", "hole4");
            case 4 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("5","3", "150m", "hole5");
            case 5 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("6","3", "155", "hole6");
            case 6 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("7","3", "80m", "hole7");
            case 7 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("8","3", "150m", "hole8");
            case 8 : return HoleFragment.newInstance("9","3", "120m", "hole9");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Each hole is adapted :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hole, container, false);
    holeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.holeText);
    holeText.setText(mParam1);
    parText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.parText);
    parText.setText(mParam2);
    distanceText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
    distanceText.setText(mParam3);
    carte = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCarte);
    Resources res = getResources();
    if(mParam4.equals("hole9")){

        Button myButton = new Button(getActivity());
        myButton.setText("Fin");
        myButton.setHeight(30);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.button_end_layout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);

    }
    String mDrawableName = mParam4;
    System.out.println(mDrawableName);
    int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
    System.out.println(resID);
    carte.setImageResource(resID);
    return v;
}
```

As you can see I dynamically add a "End" button in the 9th hole. What I want to do is to get all the scores entered in an EditText in each Fragment when the end button is clicked.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: You can maintain a list of Strings or Integers (for storing scores) in the activity that is hosting this tab layout. You can either use Interface or I would suggest use an Eventbus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for passing score data from Hole fragments to hosting activity.

Comment: but with Interface, I call the Interface method when button is clicked but I only have access to the 9th fragment score..?

Comment: You can call the interface, everytime the viewpager page is changed.